# DictCursor doesn't seem to work under psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, dictionary, psycopg2

I haven't worked with psycopg2 before but I'm trying to change the cursor factory to DictCursor so that fetchall or fetchone will return a dictionary instead of a list.

I created a test script to make things simple and only test this functionality. Here's my little bit of code that I feel should work

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=%s user=%s password=%s" % (DATABASE, USERNAME, PASSWORD))

cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory = psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
cur.execute("SELECT * from review")

res = cur.fetchall()

print type(res)
print res
```

The res variable is always a list and not a dictionary as I would expect.

A current workaround that I've implemented is to use this function that builds a dictionary and run each row returned by fetchall through it.

```
def build_dict(cursor, row):
    x = {}
    for key,col in enumerate(cursor.description):
        x[col[0]] = row[key]
    return d
```

Python is version 2.6.7 and psycopg2 is version 2.4.2.

Comment: Its astonishing how many answers are ignoring the actual problem of DictCursor not working. Half of the work arounds wont work if the DictCursor problem isnt solved.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
res = cur.fetchall()
```

makes `res` a list of `psycopg2.extras.DictRow`s.

---

Alternatively, instead of calling `cur.fetchall` you can take advantage of the fact that `cur` is an iterable:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * from review")
for row in cur:
    print(row['column_name'])
```

and thus you'll be able to access the data with `dict`-like syntax.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're spot on with "dict-like". It's a list but acts like a dictionary. That seems like a strange design decision but at least it's working now. Thanks again.

Comment: @Seth: If you want a real dictionary, use the aptly named `RealDictCursor`.

Comment: @Seth: a dictionary has no order so you couldn't use it as a tuple anymore, the first column in the query wouldn't be `row[0]` anymore but something arbitrary. So there's some merit to it :)

Comment: as @kerma specified below, [RealDictCursor](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#real-dictionary-cursor) can be used.

Optionally same effect could be achieved by dict casting the row like so: `dict_cur = (dict(row) for row in cur)`

@Seth: The docs state this for providing RealDictCursor:
_Note that this cursor is extremely specialized and does not allow the normal access (using integer indices) to fetched data. If you need to access database rows both as a dictionary and a list, then use the generic DictCursor instead of RealDictCursor._

Comment: That should probably be `for row in res:`?

Comment: @johndodo: Since `cur` itself is an iterable, you can use `for row in cur` after calling `cur.execute` (and without calling `cur.fetchall`).

Answer (score 141):

Use [`RealDictCursor`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#real-dictionary-cursor):

```py
import psycopg2.extras

cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory = psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
cur.execute("SELECT * from review")
res = cur.fetchall()
```

This gives you a list with rows as real python dictionaries instead of "advanced psycopg2 list".

Comment: Yes this works.. Filed as bug in bottle-plugin https://github.com/raisoblast/bottle-pgsql/issues/2

Comment: To solve `AttributeError: module 'psycopg2' has no attribute 'extras'` do `import psycopg2.extras`

Answer (score 19):

Another solution would be to use the [Named Tuple Cursor](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#namedtuple-cursor) since the Real Dict Cursor will break any query that uses integer indicies as explained in its documentation.

With Named Tuple Cursors, you can access them with dot syntax like so:

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras
cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory = psycopg2.extras.NamedTupleCursor)
cur.execute("SELECT * from review")
res = cur.fetchone()
res.key1
res.key2
```

This keeps things tidy and won't break anything as far as I know.

Comment: Also, the whole result can be converted to a list of dicts like this: `[row._asdict() for row in cur]`

Answer (score 5):

While this is an older question, it still comes up in google so i thought i would add my code to this for anyone else coming from the big G.

For me, i have multiple rows that i would like to return back into a dictionary and ideally dont want to use a loop or similar to set the key from a field in the database..

So using `dict comprehension syntax` i can do the following.

**Table Rows Into Dictionary**

---

```
pgCursor = Conn.cursor(cursor_factory = psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
pgCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tablename;",([]))
dictRows = {n['id']: n for n in pgCursor}
```

---

**Function & Calling It**

```
#NOTE this is using a class object hence the self param
def DBTableToDictByID(self, squery):
    self.Pointer.execute(squery,([]))
    return {n['id']: n for n in self.Pointer}

dictRows = self.DBTableToDictByID("SELECT * FROM tablename;")
```

---

While this is using a for x in y loop, its pythonic as far as i can tell....Hopefully this will be of help to some out there.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to use RealDictCursor feature, you may also have to ask for all columns
(using the * symbol after select), as is done in the answer.

I was not interested in some columns of the result, since they had known values
already used in WHERE conditions. But the `SELECT (..., ..., ..., ...) FROM ... WHERE ...`
variant didn't give me dictionaries.

Best regards !
Harley

Comment: Leave out the parentheses and your query works: `SELECT ..., ..., ..., ... FROM ... WHERE ...`.

Answer (score 0):

So to make this work like the mysql version of the Dictionary cursor you will have to wrap it in another function or code.  I will go on the forums and suggest this to them for future deployments of their code to return a dictionary when the fetchall() call is used with the Dictionary Cursor.  Here is some sample code you can use to fix for it:

```
cursor.execute(query)
# Python 2.7 and beyond with dictionary comprehension
results = [{key:value for key,value in row.iteritems()} for row in cursor]
# Python 2.6 and before
# results = [dict((key,value) for key,value in row.iteritems()) for row in cursor]
```

This code makes it the same format as the MySQL version of the dictionary cursor using fetchall().  Not sure why they implemented it differently, but this will help you get the same output of an actual python dictionary rather than a list in the fetchall() case.