# psycopg2.extras.DictCursor does not give me column names

Tags: python, psycopg2

I am using psycopg2 to access the data from the Postgres database. I am using psycopg2.extras.DictCursor for getting the data in a dict-like form using the following query:

```
try:
    self.con = psycopg2.connect(dbname=self.db, user=self.username, 
host=self.host, port=self.port)

cur = self.con.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM card")

result = cur.fetchall()

print result
```

I get the output as a list:

```
[['C01', 'card#1', 'description#1', '1'], ['C02', 'card#2', 'description#2', '1']]
```

However, I want the column names as well. I read another similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739355/dictcursor-doesnt-seem-to-work-under-psycopg2), but on trying the following I get a **KeyError**:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM card")
for row in cur:
    print(row['column_name'])
```

However, the following works:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM card")
for row in cur:
    print(row['id'])
```

Output:

```
C01
C02
```

Any ideas on how I can get the column names as well?

Comment: @BearBrown thanks, but I still get an error: 'DictCursor' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: `list(result[0].keys())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to get all column names you can use the mehtod `keys` for row item, for example:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM card")
result = cur.fetchall()
keys = list(result[0].keys()) if result else []
for row in result:
    for key in keys:
        print(row[key])
```

Comment: Just wanted to add, to get the column names, we need to convert keys to a list. Curently, it returns an iterator object