# Incorrect syntax near 'JSON' - SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2016

So I recently installed SQL Server 2016 CTP3 mainly for the JSON output feature. I am trying to using it in my SQL Query exactly like how its shown in the link below on MSDN. The keyword JSON does not turn blue and gives error "Incorrect syntax near 'JSON'"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921882%28v=sql.130%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

What could be wrong?

EDIT: I'm testing it with AdventureWorks DB for SQL Server 2016. The query is

```
SELECT * FROM Person.Contact FOR JSON AUTO
```

Comment: Can you add the query to the question

Comment: What is the database compatibility level

Comment: Run this query `ALTER DATABASE database_name 
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL =  130`. Source : [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb510680.aspx)

Comment: Not working ... Error "Valid values of the database compatibility level are 100, 110, or 120."

Comment: Did you check the link i added in previous comment. It should work if you are using Sql Server 2016

Comment: What does `select @@version` show you?

Comment: That's weird ... it shows Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64)  ... Help > About shows Sql Server 2016 CTP 3

Comment: So you are using SQL Server 2016 management studio but connecting to a 2014 instance.

Comment: Thanks guys. I solved the issue with your help.

Comment: @Amjad : I am unable to connect to 2016 instance using  Machinename\MSSQLSERVER...can u tell m how to connect to 2016 version?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. Check if compatibility level is set to SQL Server 2016 or 130
2. Connect to a 2016 instance instead of the older one. (Migrate DB)

Thanks to Martin and VR46

Comment: Mark it as answer :)

Comment: Done. Thanks again. :)

Comment: what if database says: Valid values of the database compatibility level are 100, 110, or 120.

Comment: version: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 and I'm using SQL Server 2016 Management Studio