# How can we export MySql multiple tables result-set in the JSON format?

Tags: mysql, json

Is there any way to export the result-set obtained after applying multiple joins on the several mySQL tables into the JSON format?

It could be better understood with below sample select statement

```
SELECT * FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 on table1.col = table2.col
```

I have to generate the above obtained data into JSON format. Is there any direct option/command available to the select statement by which I can do it?

Comment: You need to specify your backend language. PHP? And where you want to get JSON string? In PHP variable, MySQL resulting string or anywhere else?

Comment: You can do it by writing simple python script Ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286525/return-sql-table-as-json-in-python

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, If you are using phpmyadmin there is an option to export data to any format.**

[image]

**Click on the export button there is a dropdown to export data to any format**

[image]

**You will get JSON file with your desired result set**

[image]